# What uses does Wireshark have?

Tags: wireshark

Currently I'm using  wireshark. I am sending some HTTP and HTTPS requests and checking some captured data, finding some valid data and passing that data to make a hacking. I am a begineer in the testing field. I'm working a small company here, and I'm the only tester. I want to know what other tests Wireshark can be used for.

Comment: Hi toastmaster - I have edited your question to be less broad and opinion based, while keeping what I hope is the core question.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark is a tool that capture traffic that passes through the computer that runs it, and display to the user exactly what is being sent over the network.

Like most tools, it can be used in many ways for many purposes. It is common to use it for white hat as well as black hat activities. It is good for everything from troubleshooting network problems to pentesting and actual attacks. The tool itself does not have an inherit purpose except letting the user look at the network traffic.

It should be noted that Wireshark can only let you view traffic that is already reashing you. It can not be used to break into a network where you do not already have access.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is a tool that can be used to sniff data over Wifi. It isn't necessarily a hacking tool, but it can be used to find out information about someone or something.

For instance, if someone logs in to a HTTP website over wifi in your area, you will be able to see their login data. You can use that to login as them.

Another use I've seen for it is seeing what kind of AP's Phones are looking for when trying to connect to wifi. This way you can fake an AP that the user knows so they might connect to your fake AP and you will be able to see all kinds of data.

If you want to know more I suggest you go to the Wireshark website.

Comment: yes you said that sniff data over wifi.  Thats I want to test. please tell what should I do for testing this sniff data over wifi ?

Comment: I suggest looking up some information on Google before asking. This is what can be found using a single Google query. Goodluck, http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/

Comment: It's not specifically a WiFi monitoring tool - works for any network connection.